# What happens to reading of voltmeter connected parallel to resistor in potential divider if current is zero?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image: potential divider]

What happens to the voltmeter reading if current is in the circuit is zero, like when the whole circuit is hooked up to a potentiometer, or a switch is open? Is it just the emf of the power supply?

Comment: do you mean the current is zero in the resistor or the current in the voltmeter?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on why the current is zero.

For example, assuming an ideal voltmeter, if there is an open switch located just above the battery, as shown in FIG 1 below, the voltmeter will read zero. If there is an open switch located just below R2, as shown in FIG 2 below, the voltmeter will read the battery voltage.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The voltmeter measures the voltage drop across $R_2$. From Ohm's law, this is $V_{R_2} = I\cdot R_2$. If there is no current flowing, then $I=0$ and there is no voltage drop across $R_2$. Realistically, the voltmeter will read whatever noise there is on both the instrument and the circuit.